# Does LABEL add new layer to docker image or apply to all layers, and does it matter where LABEL is place in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

Does LABEL add new layer to docker image?

Does LABEL apply to all layers? Because pruning image based on label filter deletes all layers for that image.

Does it make any difference whether I place the LABEL at the beginning or end of the dockerfile?

Comment: I just got stuck with the same Q. It's extremely weird that you got absolutely no answers for such a long time... What I've found is the following phrases from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label): `Labels included in base or parent images (images in the FROM line) are inherited by your image. If a label already exists but with a different value, the most-recently-applied value overrides any previously-set value.`

Comment: but una dey read documentations oh 

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the builder and what you mean by layer. With the classic docker build tooling, a new label created a temporary container to capture the change. If you did this early in the build, that change could break the cache so you would put metadata like this at the end of the build.

With buildkit, it avoids temporary containers for these steps, and it ignores this metadata when looking up cached layers, so order doesn't matter for these.

For layers, you will see them in the image history, but they are defined as `"empty_layer": true`, meaning the step has no filesystem changes. There's no tar file to download for that step of the build, which is why the following image has 4 layers listed in the "rootfs" and 9 history entries:

```
$ regctl image config localhost:5000/regclient/regctl
{
  "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {
    "User": "appuser",
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Entrypoint": [
      "/regctl"
    ],
    "WorkingDir": "/",
    "Labels": {
      "maintainer": "",
      "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "Regclient contributors",
      "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2021-12-27T19:25:15Z",
      "org.opencontainers.image.description": "",
      "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://github.com/regclient/regclient",
      "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Apache 2.0",
      "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "6a1a13c410f734f5e18a6032936bc6764814eae7",
      "org.opencontainers.image.source": "git://github.com/regclient/regclient.git",
      "org.opencontainers.image.title": "regctl",
      "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/regclient/regclient",
      "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "",
      "org.opencontainers.image.version": "v0.3.10"
    }
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:132414a5f587782f893460744b6d5872335d2ccd7b668af59c36fdd83e48d3d8",
      "sha256:482fa28623966b82c52505731df79398729a36956d18b620a6434b8a147dd520",
      "sha256:8e47dcad786aa3f447bbfe6ed60b24924627535f7c10a7eb93a5c8d5d59052c2",
      "sha256:2d9d57f598a12d3cdd770ed50df2e950dad13cea14dd62444f64b2cc72873a66"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-09-20T13:39:49.998835208Z",
      "created_by": "COPY /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/ # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-09-20T13:39:50.016894649Z",
      "created_by": "COPY /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-09-20T13:39:50.043111544Z",
      "created_by": "COPY /home/appuser /home/appuser # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "COPY /src/bin/regctl /regctl # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "USER appuser",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "ENTRYPOINT [\"/regctl\"]",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "ARG BUILD_DATE",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "ARG VCS_REF",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-12-27T19:26:50.630484996Z",
      "created_by": "LABEL maintainer= org.opencontainers.image.created= org.opencontainers.image.authors=Regclient contributors org.opencontainers.image.url=https://github.com/regclient/regclient org.opencontainers.image.documentation=https://github.com/regclient/regclient org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/regclient/regclient org.opencontainers.image.version=latest org.opencontainers.image.revision= org.opencontainers.image.vendor= org.opencontainers.image.licenses=Apache 2.0 org.opencontainers.image.title=regctl org.opencontainers.image.description=",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've performed a few tests using a very simple Dockerfile, and adding a `LABEL` doesn't add any layers, but it does change the image's sha256 id.

Any change to the label's value will change the sha256 and even moving it to a different part of the Dockerfile will too, but the layers remain unaffected by the label's presence or value.

As for whether a `LABEL` "applies to all layers", I suppose we could conclude that the label is applicable to the overall *image* but has no effect on its layers.

Comment: God bless you for this straight forward answer.